# Information Link parameters to be displayed on Text area in spotfire

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I have an IL with 2 parameter ?Mindate & ?Maxdate , those parameters i want to display on the header's text area. How to add them?  As they are not the part of any tables or IL's. 
I am passing these parameters through webplayer's ConfigBlock.
My IL query is as below:

```
    SELECT F1."PROTOCOL_ID" ,
   F1."PROTOCOL_TYPE" ,
   F1."PROJECT_CODE"  ,
   F1."PROTOCOL_STATUS" 
   count(distinct case when not M2."ECG_REJECTED_PROTOCOL" is null
   and M2."ECG_REJECTED_PROTOCOL_DT"<=?Maxdate
   and  M2."ECG_REJECTED_PROTOCOL_DT" <=?Mindate
   and (M2."ECG_REJECTED_PROTOCOL_DT">=M2."ECG_DISPATCH_PROTOCOL_DT" or M2."ECG_REJECTED_PROTOCOL_DT">=M2."ECG_STORED_PROTOCOL_DT") then M2."ES_ECG_ID" end) AS "D30C6"
FROM
   "BIECGRPT"."FINANCE_REPORT_STUDIES" F1,
   "BIECGRPT"."MV_FINANCE_RPT_MAIN" M2
WHERE
   (M2."ECG_REJECTED_PROTOCOL" = F1."PROTOCOL_ID")
AND F1."PROTOCOL_ID" <> '223HV102_RV'
```

Comment: Hi Teju- The best way to do this would be to pass the parameter values to document properties (via the config block) and then pass the document properties to the IL parameters. You can easily add the document properties to a text area.

Comment: Hi Fisto, I have passed as a Config block only, I dont know now how to pass this config Block/Document properties into the text aread. 
Here is my webplayerURL with Config Block:
https://us-spotfire.solutions.iqvia.com/spotfire/wp/OpenAnalysis?file=/Team%20Folders/QECG/SMS%20Spotfire%20Reports/Dev%20Integration/FinanceReportECG&configurationBlock=Maxdate%20%3D%20%7B%2210-Mar-2018%2000%3A00%3A00%22%7D;Mindate%20%3D%20%7B%2210-Feb-2018%2000%3A00%3A00%22%7D;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A configuration block parameter is automatically assigned to a
>   document property, if a document property with the same name and data
>   type is defined in the analysis.

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/create-configuration-block-tibco-spotfire

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried it by adding a "Property Control" as "Mindate"(with same datatype which is same as my config Block parameter) . While creating it, "Value" field is mandatory  then i provided with a dummy date and saved. But in the report its displaying with the dummy date itelf not the ConfigBlock parameter value.

Comment: I could'nt see it in the editor , but in the web player its working. Cheers.